# How To Integrate Vue.Js App.Vue with .Cshtml Razor View HTML? C# Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, razor, vuejs2

I know there's a **ton** of questions very similar to this one posted here on S/O - yet I still can't find a workable solution for nicely mixing the App.vue (containing a couple custom components) and a Razor View with HTML in it.

I'm able to get the components to render on the _Layout.cshtml file, however when this occurs it overwrites all the View's HTML (from RenderBody() and all the included Partial Views.) I've been trying to use a `<slot></slot>` in a component to allow the Razor View's HTML to be passed through and live inside the Vue div.

BodyContent Component (trying to use just to pass through View's HTML):

```
<template>
    <div id="vueBody">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="myVue">
    <Header />
    <BodyContent>
      <slot></slot>
    </BodyContent>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

My _Layout.cshtml looks like this:

```
    <div id="HeaderCont">
        <div id="VueHeader">
        </div>
        <div id="MainContent">
            <div id="MainVue">
                @RenderBody() <!-- Always disappears after Vue load -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="FooterCont">
            <div id="VueFooter" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my Main.Js, I import the components and use them in the Render function like so:

```
var HeaderVue = new Vue({
    vuetify,
    store,
    render: h => h(Header)
}).$mount('#VueHeader')

var MainVue = new Vue({
    vuetify,
    store,
    render: h => h(BodyContent)
}).$mount('#MainVue')

var FooterVue = new Vue({
    vuetify,
    store,
    render: h => h(Footer)
}).$mount('#VueFooter')
```

**Am I rendering these components incorrectly?**

Note: *Using Full Build version 2.6.12 with NPM/Webpack/etc. and SFC components - but open to switching to the runtime script load way if that simplifies things.*

Comment: I don't know much Vue but `.$mount('#MainVue')` looks like it will set the `innerHTML` of that `div` with `BodyContent` component. `@RenderBody()` which is created server side will probably be replaced. Why do you have @RenderBody() where Vue renders anyway?

Comment: Hey, indeed that's the case - the mounted Vue replaces the server-side content. The @RenderBody() is there so the server-side Views are rendered in between the Vue components. If I move @RenderBody() out of the Vue-controlled divs, I can't control the View html in the Vue ecosystem. Thanks for responding!

Comment: *Usually*, it's the other way around. The dynamic content of the body would be controlled by Vue or other frameworks and the login, session, cookies and layout menus are created server-side by MVC

Comment: I'm integrating into an existing MVC project, so I'm trying wrap the existing content coming from the Views with Vue, so I can inject Vue components anywhere and control everything from Vue. Thanks!